# Make multiple column of gridview readyonly=true,false from my front end not from the hardcore coding Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, readonly

Using Asp.net webforms website
I need the grid view columns to be handled from the admin panel. so admin has the option to restrict or allow the user to make changes in that particular row of the column grid view with the help of `ReadOnly=""` Option.
how is this possible with the database?

I can use either item template or bound field.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You don't normally restrict editing of rows by user. You pull data based on the user's logon and they see their own data. Fill that grid based on the user ID -  that's how most sites work. You seem to suggest that you want to display some rows - but based on the user, only SOME of the rows can be edited? If you only pull their rows based on their logon ID, then you really don't have this problem. And you don't mention what security process you plan to use? Will you say add or remove membership in a given security group (role) then? What criteria for 10 users to edit, and 10 others not to edit?